# No puedo iniciar sesión en mi página de WAMP

Tags: wordpress, wamp

Verán, tengo una página web en modo local utilizando WAMP.
La página en si funciona, pero hay una página que falla, la de iniciar sesión.
La página de WAMP es C:\wamp64\www\prueba, por lo que para iniciar sesión, escribo http://localhost/prueba/wordpress/wp-admin/, y me encuentro con esto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
¿Como arreglo este extraño problema?

Answer (score 0):

Ya lo arreglé.
Resulta que en la dirección que estaba escribiendo, el wordpress sobraba, siendo solo http://localhost/prueba/wp-admin/.
Cuando lo instale, hubo un tiempo que tenia dentro de la carpeta www una carpeta prueba, en la cual estaba la carpeta wordpress, en la cual estaba el contenido de la página. Como saque el contenido de wordpress y elimine esa carpeta, ya no hacia falta. De ahí el error.